# Jquery: dynamically change an img src based on dropdown selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, onchange

I would like to dynamically display an image after the user has selected it. The different options are generated from a SQL query.

It works when I specify the image as a value:

```
<select id="SelectLogo" onchange="document.getElementById('logo').src='/images/'+this.value" >
   <option value="img1.png">Image 1</option>
   <option value="img2.png">Image 2</option>
   <option value="img3.png">Image 3</option>
</select>
<img id="logo" src="">
```

But now I need to post an Id but not the image name. I have tried that:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectLogo" onchange="document.getElementById('logo').src='/images/'+$(this).attr('data-img')" >
    <option value="1" data-img="img1.png">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-img="img2.png">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-img="img3.png">Image 3</option>
</select>    
<img id="logo" src="">
```

I got an error : undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(this).find('option:selected').data('img')` to get the selected option data-attribute.

***Demo Code*** :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectLogo" onchange="document.getElementById('logo').src='/images/'+$(this).find('option:selected').data('img')" >
   <option value="1" data-img="img1.png">Image 1</option>
   <option value="2" data-img="img2.png">Image 2</option>
   <option value="3" data-img="img3.png">Image 3</option>
</select>

<img id="logo" src="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use jquery `change` event handler instead of javascript `onchange` attribute. Using this way you can fire change event on page load and set image `src` in page load.

```
$("#SelectLogo").change(function(){
  $("#logo").attr("src", '/images/'+$(":selected", this).data('img'));
}).change();
```

```js
$("#SelectLogo").change(function(){
  $("#logo").attr("src", '/images/'+$(":selected", this).data('img'));
  console.log($("#logo").attr("src"));
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectLogo">
   <option value="1" data-img="img1.png">Image 1</option>
   <option value="2" data-img="img2.png">Image 2</option>
   <option value="3" data-img="img3.png">Image 3</option>
</select>
<img id="logo" src="">
```